# D3.js labeled force graph does not reload data

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to create a force graph in d3.js with some labels on top of each node and also some content-dependent style (for instance, the colour of the node is dependent on a 'type' property). I am starting with one of the [examples](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642) but I cannot make the graph to display new data when I update it. For instance, when changing the text property on the list of data, the label on the node should change, however it does not. I think the problem might be in the `data()`/`enter()` procedure, which I am still trying to fully understand. What I have so far managed to get is the following: https://jsfiddle.net/5Luv0btd/2/ . Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because once you've entered the data, you do not have to operate on the `nodeEnter` anymore. The reason is simple: `.enter()` [**merges into the update selection when you append or insert.**](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md#user-content-enter). In other words, after chaining `.enter()`, `node` effectively refers to both the old and new data. Citing the example for the v3.x documentation for d3:

```
var update_sel = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data)
update_sel.attr(/* operate on old elements only */)
update_sel.enter().append("circle").attr(/* operate on new elements only */)
update_sel.attr(/* operate on old and new elements */)
update_sel.exit().remove() /* complete the enter-update-exit pattern */
```

Therefore, working with `node` itself will suffice, i.e.:

```
// Enter selection
node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(drag);

// From this point onwards:
// `node` will refer to both old and new data

// Do magic ;)
node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style('fill', function(d) {
      return color(d.type)
    })
    .attr("width", 16)
    .attr("height", 16);

node.append("text")
    .attr("dx", 0)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle");
```

See working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/5Luv0btd/5/, or refer to the code snippet below:

```js
var data = {
  "nodes": [{
    "name": "Myriel",
    "type": 1
  }, {
    "name": "Napoleon",
    "type": 1
  }, {
    "name": "Mlle.Baptistine",
    "type": 1
  }, {
    "name": "Mme.Magloire",
    "type": 1
  }, {
    "name": "CountessdeLo",
    "type": 1
  }, {
    "name": "Geborand",
    "type": 1
  }, {
    "name": "Champtercier",
    "type": 1
  }, {
    "name": "Cravatte",
    "type": 1
  }, {
    "name": "Count",
    "type": 1
  }, {
    "name": "OldMan",
    "type": 1
  }, {
    "name": "Labarre",
    "type": 2
  }, {
    "name": "Valjean",
    "type": 2
  }, {
    "name": "Marguerite",
    "type": 3
  }, {
    "name": "Mme.deR",
    "type": 2
  }, {
    "name": "Isabeau",
    "type": 2
  }, {
    "name": "Gervais",
    "type": 2
  }, {
    "name": "Tholomyes",
    "type": 3
  }, {
    "name": "Listolier",
    "type": 3
  }, {
    "name": "Fameuil",
    "type": 3
  }, {
    "name": "Blacheville",
    "type": 3
  }, {
    "name": "Favourite",
    "type": 3
  }, {
    "name": "Dahlia",
    "type": 3
  }, {
    "name": "Zephine",
    "type": 3
  }, {
    "name": "Fantine",
    "type": 3
  }, {
    "name": "Mme.Thenardier",
    "type": 4
  }, {
    "name": "Thenardier",
    "type": 4
  }, {
    "name": "Cosette",
    "type": 5
  }, {
    "name": "Javert",
    "type": 4
  }, {
    "name": "Fauchelevent",
    "type": 0
  }, {
    "name": "Bamatabois",
    "type": 2
  }, {
    "name": "Perpetue",
    "type": 3
  }, {
    "name": "Simplice",
    "type": 2
  }, {
    "name": "Scaufflaire",
    "type": 2
  }, {
    "name": "Woman1",
    "type": 2
  }, {
    "name": "Judge",
    "type": 2
  }, {
    "name": "Champmathieu",
    "type": 2
  }, {
    "name": "Brevet",
    "type": 2
  }, {
    "name": "Chenildieu",
    "type": 2
  }, {
    "name": "Cochepaille",
    "type": 2
  }, {
    "name": "Pontmercy",
    "type": 4
  }, {
    "name": "Boulatruelle",
    "type": 6
  }, {
    "name": "Eponine",
    "type": 4
  }, {
    "name": "Anzelma",
    "type": 4
  }, {
    "name": "Woman2",
    "type": 5
  }, {
    "name": "MotherInnocent",
    "type": 0
  }, {
    "name": "Gribier",
    "type": 0
  }, {
    "name": "Jondrette",
    "type": 7
  }, {
    "name": "Mme.Burgon",
    "type": 7
  }, {
    "name": "Gavroche",
    "type": 8
  }, {
    "name": "Gillenormand",
    "type": 5
  }, {
    "name": "Magnon",
    "type": 5
  }, {
    "name": "Mlle.Gillenormand",
    "type": 5
  }, {
    "name": "Mme.Pontmercy",
    "type": 5
  }, {
    "name": "Mlle.Vaubois",
    "type": 5
  }, {
    "name": "Lt.Gillenormand",
    "type": 5
  }, {
    "name": "Marius",
    "type": 8
  }, {
    "name": "BaronessT",
    "type": 5
  }, {
    "name": "Mabeuf",
    "type": 8
  }, {
    "name": "Enjolras",
    "type": 8
  }, {
    "name": "Combeferre",
    "type": 8
  }, {
    "name": "Prouvaire",
    "type": 8
  }, {
    "name": "Feuilly",
    "type": 8
  }, {
    "name": "Courfeyrac",
    "type": 8
  }, {
    "name": "Bahorel",
    "type": 8
  }, {
    "name": "Bossuet",
    "type": 8
  }, {
    "name": "Joly",
    "type": 8
  }, {
    "name": "Grantaire",
    "type": 8
  }, {
    "name": "MotherPlutarch",
    "type": 9
  }, {
    "name": "Gueulemer",
    "type": 4
  }, {
    "name": "Babet",
    "type": 4
  }, {
    "name": "Claquesous",
    "type": 4
  }, {
    "name": "Montparnasse",
    "type": 4
  }, {
    "name": "Toussaint",
    "type": 5
  }, {
    "name": "Child1",
    "type": 10
  }, {
    "name": "Child2",
    "type": 10
  }, {
    "name": "Brujon",
    "type": 4
  }, {
    "name": "Mme.Hucheloup",
    "type": 8
  }],
  "links": [{
    "source": 1,
    "target": 0,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 2,
    "target": 0,
    "value": 8
  }, {
    "source": 3,
    "target": 0,
    "value": 10
  }, {
    "source": 3,
    "target": 2,
    "value": 6
  }, {
    "source": 4,
    "target": 0,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 5,
    "target": 0,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 0,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 7,
    "target": 0,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 8,
    "target": 0,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 9,
    "target": 0,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 11,
    "target": 10,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 11,
    "target": 3,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 11,
    "target": 2,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 11,
    "target": 0,
    "value": 5
  }, {
    "source": 12,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 13,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 14,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 15,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 17,
    "target": 16,
    "value": 4
  }, {
    "source": 18,
    "target": 16,
    "value": 4
  }, {
    "source": 18,
    "target": 17,
    "value": 4
  }, {
    "source": 19,
    "target": 16,
    "value": 4
  }, {
    "source": 19,
    "target": 17,
    "value": 4
  }, {
    "source": 19,
    "target": 18,
    "value": 4
  }, {
    "source": 20,
    "target": 16,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 20,
    "target": 17,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 20,
    "target": 18,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 20,
    "target": 19,
    "value": 4
  }, {
    "source": 21,
    "target": 16,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 21,
    "target": 17,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 21,
    "target": 18,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 21,
    "target": 19,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 21,
    "target": 20,
    "value": 5
  }, {
    "source": 22,
    "target": 16,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 22,
    "target": 17,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 22,
    "target": 18,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 22,
    "target": 19,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 22,
    "target": 20,
    "value": 4
  }, {
    "source": 22,
    "target": 21,
    "value": 4
  }, {
    "source": 23,
    "target": 16,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 23,
    "target": 17,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 23,
    "target": 18,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 23,
    "target": 19,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 23,
    "target": 20,
    "value": 4
  }, {
    "source": 23,
    "target": 21,
    "value": 4
  }, {
    "source": 23,
    "target": 22,
    "value": 4
  }, {
    "source": 23,
    "target": 12,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 23,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 9
  }, {
    "source": 24,
    "target": 23,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 24,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 7
  }, {
    "source": 25,
    "target": 24,
    "value": 13
  }, {
    "source": 25,
    "target": 23,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 25,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 12
  }, {
    "source": 26,
    "target": 24,
    "value": 4
  }, {
    "source": 26,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 31
  }, {
    "source": 26,
    "target": 16,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 26,
    "target": 25,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 27,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 17
  }, {
    "source": 27,
    "target": 23,
    "value": 5
  }, {
    "source": 27,
    "target": 25,
    "value": 5
  }, {
    "source": 27,
    "target": 24,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 27,
    "target": 26,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 28,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 8
  }, {
    "source": 28,
    "target": 27,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 29,
    "target": 23,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 29,
    "target": 27,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 29,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 30,
    "target": 23,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 31,
    "target": 30,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 31,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 31,
    "target": 23,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 31,
    "target": 27,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 32,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 33,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 33,
    "target": 27,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 34,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 34,
    "target": 29,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 35,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 35,
    "target": 34,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 35,
    "target": 29,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 36,
    "target": 34,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 36,
    "target": 35,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 36,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 36,
    "target": 29,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 37,
    "target": 34,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 37,
    "target": 35,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 37,
    "target": 36,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 37,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 37,
    "target": 29,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 38,
    "target": 34,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 38,
    "target": 35,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 38,
    "target": 36,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 38,
    "target": 37,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 38,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 38,
    "target": 29,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 39,
    "target": 25,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 40,
    "target": 25,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 41,
    "target": 24,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 41,
    "target": 25,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 42,
    "target": 41,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 42,
    "target": 25,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 42,
    "target": 24,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 43,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 43,
    "target": 26,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 43,
    "target": 27,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 44,
    "target": 28,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 44,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 45,
    "target": 28,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 47,
    "target": 46,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 48,
    "target": 47,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 48,
    "target": 25,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 48,
    "target": 27,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 48,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 49,
    "target": 26,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 49,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 50,
    "target": 49,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 50,
    "target": 24,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 51,
    "target": 49,
    "value": 9
  }, {
    "source": 51,
    "target": 26,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 51,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 52,
    "target": 51,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 52,
    "target": 39,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 53,
    "target": 51,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 54,
    "target": 51,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 54,
    "target": 49,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 54,
    "target": 26,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 55,
    "target": 51,
    "value": 6
  }, {
    "source": 55,
    "target": 49,
    "value": 12
  }, {
    "source": 55,
    "target": 39,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 55,
    "target": 54,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 55,
    "target": 26,
    "value": 21
  }, {
    "source": 55,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 19
  }, {
    "source": 55,
    "target": 16,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 55,
    "target": 25,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 55,
    "target": 41,
    "value": 5
  }, {
    "source": 55,
    "target": 48,
    "value": 4
  }, {
    "source": 56,
    "target": 49,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 56,
    "target": 55,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 57,
    "target": 55,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 57,
    "target": 41,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 57,
    "target": 48,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 58,
    "target": 55,
    "value": 7
  }, {
    "source": 58,
    "target": 48,
    "value": 7
  }, {
    "source": 58,
    "target": 27,
    "value": 6
  }, {
    "source": 58,
    "target": 57,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 58,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 4
  }, {
    "source": 59,
    "target": 58,
    "value": 15
  }, {
    "source": 59,
    "target": 55,
    "value": 5
  }, {
    "source": 59,
    "target": 48,
    "value": 6
  }, {
    "source": 59,
    "target": 57,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 60,
    "target": 48,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 60,
    "target": 58,
    "value": 4
  }, {
    "source": 60,
    "target": 59,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 61,
    "target": 48,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 61,
    "target": 58,
    "value": 6
  }, {
    "source": 61,
    "target": 60,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 61,
    "target": 59,
    "value": 5
  }, {
    "source": 61,
    "target": 57,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 61,
    "target": 55,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 62,
    "target": 55,
    "value": 9
  }, {
    "source": 62,
    "target": 58,
    "value": 17
  }, {
    "source": 62,
    "target": 59,
    "value": 13
  }, {
    "source": 62,
    "target": 48,
    "value": 7
  }, {
    "source": 62,
    "target": 57,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 62,
    "target": 41,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 62,
    "target": 61,
    "value": 6
  }, {
    "source": 62,
    "target": 60,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 63,
    "target": 59,
    "value": 5
  }, {
    "source": 63,
    "target": 48,
    "value": 5
  }, {
    "source": 63,
    "target": 62,
    "value": 6
  }, {
    "source": 63,
    "target": 57,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 63,
    "target": 58,
    "value": 4
  }, {
    "source": 63,
    "target": 61,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 63,
    "target": 60,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 63,
    "target": 55,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 64,
    "target": 55,
    "value": 5
  }, {
    "source": 64,
    "target": 62,
    "value": 12
  }, {
    "source": 64,
    "target": 48,
    "value": 5
  }, {
    "source": 64,
    "target": 63,
    "value": 4
  }, {
    "source": 64,
    "target": 58,
    "value": 10
  }, {
    "source": 64,
    "target": 61,
    "value": 6
  }, {
    "source": 64,
    "target": 60,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 64,
    "target": 59,
    "value": 9
  }, {
    "source": 64,
    "target": 57,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 64,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 65,
    "target": 63,
    "value": 5
  }, {
    "source": 65,
    "target": 64,
    "value": 7
  }, {
    "source": 65,
    "target": 48,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 65,
    "target": 62,
    "value": 5
  }, {
    "source": 65,
    "target": 58,
    "value": 5
  }, {
    "source": 65,
    "target": 61,
    "value": 5
  }, {
    "source": 65,
    "target": 60,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 65,
    "target": 59,
    "value": 5
  }, {
    "source": 65,
    "target": 57,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 65,
    "target": 55,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 66,
    "target": 64,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 66,
    "target": 58,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 66,
    "target": 59,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 66,
    "target": 62,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 66,
    "target": 65,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 66,
    "target": 48,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 66,
    "target": 63,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 66,
    "target": 61,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 66,
    "target": 60,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 67,
    "target": 57,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 68,
    "target": 25,
    "value": 5
  }, {
    "source": 68,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 68,
    "target": 24,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 68,
    "target": 27,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 68,
    "target": 48,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 68,
    "target": 41,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 69,
    "target": 25,
    "value": 6
  }, {
    "source": 69,
    "target": 68,
    "value": 6
  }, {
    "source": 69,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 69,
    "target": 24,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 69,
    "target": 27,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 69,
    "target": 48,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 69,
    "target": 41,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 70,
    "target": 25,
    "value": 4
  }, {
    "source": 70,
    "target": 69,
    "value": 4
  }, {
    "source": 70,
    "target": 68,
    "value": 4
  }, {
    "source": 70,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 70,
    "target": 24,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 70,
    "target": 27,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 70,
    "target": 41,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 70,
    "target": 58,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 71,
    "target": 27,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 71,
    "target": 69,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 71,
    "target": 68,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 71,
    "target": 70,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 71,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 71,
    "target": 48,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 71,
    "target": 41,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 71,
    "target": 25,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 72,
    "target": 26,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 72,
    "target": 27,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 72,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 73,
    "target": 48,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 74,
    "target": 48,
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": 74,
    "target": 73,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 75,
    "target": 69,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 75,
    "target": 68,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 75,
    "target": 25,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "source": 75,
    "target": 48,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 75,
    "target": 41,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 75,
    "target": 70,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 75,
    "target": 71,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 76,
    "target": 64,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 76,
    "target": 65,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 76,
    "target": 66,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 76,
    "target": 63,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 76,
    "target": 62,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 76,
    "target": 48,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 76,
    "target": 58,
    "value": 1
  }]
};

var width = 960,
  height = 500,
  color = d3.scale.category20();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var force = d3.layout.force()
  .gravity(0.05)
  .distance(100)
  .charge(-100)
  .size([width, height]);

var draw = function(data) {
  
  force
    .nodes(data.nodes)
    .links(data.links)
    .start();

  var drag = d3.behavior.drag().origin(function(d) {
    return d;
  });

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(data.links);

  var linkEnter = link.enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link");

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(data.nodes, function(d) {
      return d.name
    });

  node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(drag);

  node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style('fill', function(d) {
      return color(d.type)
    })
    .attr("width", 16)
    .attr("height", 16);

  node.append("text")
    .attr("dx", 0)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle");
  link.exit().remove();
  node.exit().remove();

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) {
        return d.source.x;
      })
      .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return d.source.y;
      })
      .attr("x2", function(d) {
        return d.target.x;
      })
      .attr("y2", function(d) {
        return d.target.y;
      });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
  });
}
draw(data);

setTimeout(function(d) {
  data.nodes[0].name = "A changed name";
  data.nodes[0].type = 2;

  // The node 'Myriel' should now have the labed 'A changed name'
  draw(data)

}, 2000);
```

```css
.link {
  stroke: #ccc;
}

.node text {
  pointer-events: none;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```